# Normal $(\frac{n-1}{n})$-percentile asymptotic to $(2\log n)^{1/2}$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am working from Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, and I have encountered the following question:

> Suppose that $X$ is normally distributed, and $b_n$ is defined by $P(X>b_n)=\frac1n$. Show that $b_n\sim (2\log n)^{1/2}.$

I'm confused about how this could be true. We know that $P(X>x)$ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}x}e^{-x^2/2}$, and so we should get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}b_n}e^{-b_n^2/2}}=1$$

Heuristically, this seems unlikely, right? Since if we just replace $b_n$ with $(2\log n)^{1/2}$ we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(2\log n)^{1/2}}\cdot\frac1n}=1,$$

which is obviously wrong.

Even if we try to go through a more rigorous formulation, I'm just not seeing where a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ is going to come from.

Comment: Isn't it that there exists $b_n$ such that $b_n^2/2\ln n\to1$ and the limit you want is also $1$?

Comment: @yo': I don't understand what you're saying. Surely such a $b_n$ exists; what does it have to do with this $b_n$?

Comment: Well, if such $b_n$ exists, then it is the $b_n$ that solves $P(X>b_n)=1/n$, isn't it?

Comment: @yo': My definition of $b_n$ is that $P(X>b_n)=1/n$; given that, I need to find its asymptotic behavior. It sounds like you are looking at a sequence with some asymptotic behavior and trying to say that it satisfies $P(X>b_n)=1/n$? That shouldn't work, since, e.g. there are lots of sequences with the same asymptotic behavior, and only one with the probability property. So I think I am misunderstanding.

Comment: But in the last displayed equation, you plug $\sqrt{2\log n}$ in the formula, which cannot be done; the fact that $b_n/\sqrt{2\log n}\to1$ does not mean that $f(b_n)$ and $f(\sqrt{2\log n})$ have the same limit, where $f(x)$ is the complicated fraction. You are basically doing a limiting per partes, which works only in some well defined cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31578/discussion-between-yo-and-eric-stucky).